# How data binding is working in filters in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

This is my button

```
<button ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="selectCategory(item)">{{item}</button>
```

And this is my controller

```
.controller("productListCtrl", function ($scope) {
    let selectedCategory = null;

    $scope.selectCategory = function (item) {
        selectedCategory = item;
    };
    $scope.categoryFilterFn = function (product) {
        return selectedCategory == null || product.category == selectedCategory;
    }
});
```

I have created method `categoryFilterFn` for `filter` filter and I use it in other part of my code

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in data| filter:categoryFilterFn" class="well">
```

so I use `filter` for this div. When the page is loaded first time filter is working, but when I click button it goes to `selectCategory()` function and changes the value of `selectedCategory` variable(which is not even a `$scope` property, just a variable). After that angular filters the `ng-repeat` again. I want to understand why ? I understand that my variable `selectedCategory` is used in `categoryFilterFn` function (which is filter), but does it mean that every change of it will cause new rendering ?

Comment: consider binding `$scope.selectedCategory`

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs in every change detection filter gets executed. When you are invoking `$scope.selectCategory` function angular internally run the digest cycle and firing events to identify the changes happening in the scope. So each digest cycle or change detection filters are gonna fire again.